# Hex to Closest Color Name in Array

Tags: javascript, colors, euclidean-distance

Trying to convert hex colors to color names, any ideas on how to proceed?
Example, given color: #006338

This hex should translate to "Green" based off the following array:

```
[BLACK, GRAY, WHITE, RED, PURPLE, PINK, GREEN, YELLOW, ORANGE, BROWN, BLUE, TURQUOISE]
```

Anybody aware of any techniques to compare the hex color to the colors in the array and present the closest match?

Thank you.

Comment: If you get the HSL conversion of the hex value, you can use the Hue channel and assign ranges for each color name depending on the Hue. Then you can get the closest match... you may need to take in account the L component for white and black

Comment: take a look : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159830/nearest-color-algorithm-using-hex-triplet

Comment: @api55 you will also need to look at luminosity to distinguish pink from red, orange from brown. And you will need saturation to tell when a color should be labeled gray.

Comment: @MarkMeyer true, I almost forgot about it. But the general idea is there, it is usually better than using RGB colorspace.